# How to draw right angled triangle with python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
def drawTri(a):
    b = (a*math.tan(45))
    c = (a/math.cos(45))

    t.forward(a)
    t.left(135)
    t.forward(c)
    t.left(135)
    t.forward(b)
```

[image]

Comment: minimal working example please. `import` and `t` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import turtle

def drawTri(a):
    hyp = a * 2**0.5
    s = turtle.Screen()
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    t.forward(a)
    t.left(135)
    t.forward(hyp)
    t.left(135)
    t.forward(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is close to that described in [Basic trigonometry isn't working correctly in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32980003/basic-trigonometry-isnt-working-correctly-in-python/32980217)

The turtle module uses degrees for angles, the math module uses radians

To calculate the cosine of 45 degrees you can use

```
math.cos(math.radians(45))
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can also switch the turtle to use radians via `turtle.radians()` and then calculate `math.cos(math.pi / 4)`

Answer (score 0):

Who needs angles?

```
def drawTri(a):
    x, y = turtle.position()
    turtle.setx(x + a)
    turtle.sety(y + a)
    turtle.goto(x, y)
```

Comment: Isn't the goto statement considered harmful :)

Answer (score 0):

i made a relay simple way of making a right angle triangle i also added some other helpful things to know about python turtle that is you didn't already know them they should be helpful(i know you already have an answer but i just think that this is a much simpler way)

```
import turtle
t = turtle
f = t.forward
r = t.right
t.color('blue','yellow')
t.begin_fill()
f(70)
r(135)
f(100)
r(135)
f(70)
r(135)
t.end_fill()

t.penup()
t.setposition(-50,30)
t.pendown()
t.color('blue','yellow')
t.begin_fill()
f(70)
r(135)
f(100)
r(135)
f(70)
r(135)
t.end_fill()
```

there are two triangles there and its the extra stuff that makes it so bulky