# kotlin.math.sin(Double) <> Windows Calculator Sin output

Tags: android, kotlin

The kotlin.math.sin(Double) result is not same with the windows scientific calculator result. Im still a beginner in kotlin Android Studio. Please help.

Below are the screenshots of my problem.

**[Windows Scientific calculator Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiGb1.jpg) **0.17364817766693034885171662676931****

[Android Studio (Kotlin) Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWkD1.jpg)
**-0.5440211108893698**

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Duplicate of [Unusual Math with incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691800/unusual-math-with-incorrect-results) - Note the language is irrelevant, the problem is the same and is solved the same way

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin is [expecting radians](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/sin.html) and calculator is expecting degrees.

Comment: To be precise the windows calculator has a toggle button marked `DEG` or `RAD` for toggling between the two

Comment: Thank you. How can I convert my kotlin.math.sin (RAD) to kotlin.math.sin (DEG) in my program?

Comment: To convert RAD to DEG there's the function `Math.toDegrees(double rad)`